# Using Max Count after joining two tables in MySql

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am just a beginner in MySql and I am trying to display the worker ID, full name and the maximum number of assignments issued to a particular employee(worker). The two tables worker and assignment are related through Wrk_ID.

My code is not working.

```
SELECT w.Wrk_ID, 
CONCAT_WS(" ", Wrk_FirstName, Wrk_Initial, Wrk_LastName) AS FullName,
COUNT(a.Wrk_ID) AS count
FROM worker w LEFT JOIN assignment a
ON w.Wrk_ID = a.Wrk_ID
GROUP BY w.Wrk_ID
HAVING count = ALL(SELECT MAX(a.Wrk_ID) FROM assignment GROUP BY Wrk_ID);
```

Really need assistance!...Thanks

Comment: Beginner or otherwise, this must look odd: `SELECT MAX(a.Wrk_ID) FROM assignment GROUP BY Wrk_ID`

Comment: Suggest you provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH the desired result set.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT distinct w.Wrk_ID, 
CONCAT_WS(" ", Wrk_FirstName, Wrk_Initial, Wrk_LastName) AS FullName,
COUNT(a.Wrk_ID) AS count
FROM worker w LEFT JOIN assignment a
ON w.Wrk_ID = a.Wrk_ID
GROUP BY w.Wrk_ID
HAVING count >= ALL(SELECT count(Wrk_ID) FROM assignment GROUP BY Wrk_ID);
```

SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6e2b/10

Comment: Thanks @potatopeelings  the query works now. God Bless.

Comment: Super generous to make a SQL fiddle for this. Thanks for being a great community member @potatopeelings